# Any good example projects for the Kiwi testing library (offering more complexity than 2+2)

Tags: ios, objective-c, tdd, kiwi

I'm looking for a good example project/tutorial that show the Kiwi testing framework in action. I don't need any more examples of testing classes with the only purpose of adding 2 numbers together or something mundane like that. There are plenty of those examples already.

I'm particularly interested in strategies for testing UIViewController subclasses and classes that are in charge of data fetching.

What are the strategies that exist for testing against a web service. Is it to stub out the return methods from the fetch calls?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a website related to the book "Test Driven iOS Development with Kiwi"
You could find out code samples and in-depth tutorial over here.

http://editorscut.com/Books/001kiwi/001kiwi-details.html

I tried it out myself and it is great, especially if you are getting started with Kiwi on iOS.
The website also has a link to the github with code samples.

https://github.com/editorscut/ec001-iOS-Testing-With-Kiwi

Comment: The primary link is dead now. New one: http://editorscut.com/Books/TestDrivingIOSDevelopmentWithKiwi/bookPage.html

Answer (score 4):

Thi is good link to see, how to use Kiwi for testing:

https://github.com/IgorFedorchuk/use-bdd

Answer (score 4):

[mneorr](https://github.com/mneorr) on Github seems to test most of his projects with Kiwi these days. I also think he is a collaborator on the Kiwi project itself. The following projects use Kiwi for unit tests with varying degrees of coverage:

- [Objective-Record](https://github.com/mneorr/Objective-Record)
- [ObjectiveSugar](https://github.com/mneorr/ObjectiveSugar)
- [Alcatraz](https://github.com/mneorr/Alcatraz)

I've used Kiwi to test [this](https://github.com/lukestringer90/ShakingAlertView) project. I don't profess to be a unit testing/TDD/BDD/Kiwi master but maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

Just throwing my two cents, the actual [wiki for the Kiwi git's project](https://github.com/allending/Kiwi/wiki) has some nice examples:

- https://github.com/allending/Kiwi/wiki/Specs
- https://github.com/allending/Kiwi/wiki/Mocks-and-Stubs